# MapObjects - Class not registered - cannot change platform to x86, unable to add it as a platform

Tags: c#, asp.net, esri-arc-engine

I inherited an ASP.NET web application at work, and while trying to set it up locally, it doesn't seem to run on my machine. I received the following error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {9BD6A64F-CE75-11D1-AF04-204C4F4F5020} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Errors out on this line:

```
public MapObjects2.DataConnection dc = new MapObjects2.DataConnectionClass();
```

I am trying to force x86, as per instructions I found else where... however Visual Studio is not having it.

See below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

So my question is, why won't it let me select x86, and how do I force it? I tried typing in x86 for a new solution platform, but I don't think that works.

Or is this even my problem? Should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't that the project wasn't running in 32 bit mode. The issue was that MapObjects wasn't installed! Even though the .dll was present in the project files itself, MapObjects in its entirety needed to be installed.

This may present a problem for future developers, since you can't purchase Map Objects from ESRI anymore.